# Use Color Html tag in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a html input tag with color type in my view

```
 <input type="color" id="Color" />
```

but when i submit button in action method Color in my model has been Null Value

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: I Get it.Specify the name attribute also in the input tag. name attribute will be binded on post and not id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing ViewModels ,**Try to keep your Property types as simple as possible.** I would change your property to simple `string` type and use the same name in your form for the Model binding to work.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Color { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

In the view

```
<input type="color" name="Color" id="Color" />
```

Remember that color input is [not](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-color.php) supported by all browsers.

Comment: tnx this is just sample from tdd book