# MVC binding not working for input type color

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, color-picker

I am using an MVC application and one of the fields is of type color. Below is the code.

Model :

```
public string ColorVal { get; set; }
```

View :

```
<div id="divColor" class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ColorVal" class="col-md-4 control-label">New Color</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input asp-for="ColorVal" type="color" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

The issue is while the code works fine interms of color being changed, the value is not bound to the model property and so ColorVal is null in the POST action in the controller.

What am I missing?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12395158/4761773) does not seem to be working.

Comment: have u checked if it supports your browser? https://caniuse.com/#search=color

Comment: @HastaTamang Yeah,it works in my version of Chrome and I can see the color changing. The issue is that the binding is not happening.

Comment: does it work if you just do plain `<input type="color" name="ColorVal" id="ColorVal" />`

Comment: @HastaTamang Thanks. That works. I do not have an explanation but it seems to be working fine

Comment: np mate, as long as it works, we r happy

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add name attribute

```
   <input asp-for="ColorVal" name="ColorVal"  type="color" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: `<input as-for=expression>` Generates the id and name HTML attributes for the expression name specified in the asp-for attribute